# Table 'mlinksqlaugust.account_access_grants' doesn't exist While importing new database !!! i am getting this error

Tags: mysql, database, import, xampp

C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p MlinkSQLaugust < "C:\xampp\htdocs\MlinkDB\mlinkdbaugust\DEV1130521.sql"
Enter password:
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 38: Table 'mlinksqlaugust.account_access_grants' doesn't exist

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account_access_grants`;
CREATE TABLE `account_access_grants` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `module` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: the above sql command added its deleted and added a table but its asking for all the tables to do the same

Comment: later i got this issue C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p mlinksql < "C:\xampp\htdocs\MlinkDB\newdb\DEV1130521.sql"
Enter password:
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 16: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'